# wrong encoding using knitr on bibentry

Tags: input-encodings, knitr, bibentry

I'm trying to cite packages used following this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43888025/8146116 I change the bibentry style to latex but I get the warning:

> Warning: :0-4: Some input could not be re-encoded to ASCII}

with non-english characters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\bold\textbf %this is necessary 
\begin{document}
<<r_list, echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
  citations <- function(includeURL = TRUE, includeRStudio = FALSE) {
  if(includeRStudio == TRUE) {
    ref.rstudio <- RStudio.Version()$citation
    if(includeURL == FALSE) {
      ref.rstudio$url = NULL;
    }
    print(ref.rstudio, style = 'text')
    cat('\n')
  }

  cit.list <- c('base', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs))  
  for(i in 1:length(cit.list)) {
    ref <- citation(cit.list[i])
    if(includeURL == FALSE) {
      ref$url = NULL;
    }
    a=format(ref, style = 'latex') 
    cat(a)
    cat('\\par ')
  }
}

library(tidyverse)
citations()
@
\end{document}
```

Also how can I use RStudio.Version() outside of RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Nice first question.

Note: This solution requires a working installation of `R`. Execute in `RStudio` or  [alternative editors for knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/).

**Step 1.**
Check your file encoding settings in `RStudio`. Go to `Tools > Code > Saving > Default text encoding` and chose `UTF-8`. Read Yihui's discussion about file encoding [here](https://yihui.name/en/2018/11/biggest-regret-knitr/). There is a ç (cedilla) in the name (François) of one of the authors of the `dpylr` package and if `UTF-8` is not set on the file encoding it will generate an error. Use of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble of the `tex` file is also recommended.

**Step 2.**
The `R` chunk produces a list of loaded packages. For each package, the citation is retrieved by combining the `base` package with the packages listed in `names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)`, using the function `citation`. The structure of the output from the `citation` function is a list. This is converted to a variable `ref` with a `BibEntry` structure using the `as.BibEntry` function from the `RefManageR` package. `ref` is then written to a `bib` file using the `WriteBib` function, also from  the `RefManageR` package.

**Step 3.**
From there, `LaTeX` takes over. The `bib` file is declared in the preamble using `\addbibresource`. The formatting is done using `biblatex` and `Biber`. All the package citations are output using `\nocite{*}` and `\printbibliography`.

There are two particular benefits of this approach versus the original method. First, the `bib` file is written to disk. It can be imported into a bibliographic database (e.g. `JabRef`) and manipulated, if necessary. Second, by invoking `biblatex` and `biber`, we have a lot of control over the formatting of the output, and where the bibliography of packages appears in our document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{packages.bib}

\begin{document}
  <<r_list,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results='asis',tidy=TRUE>>=
  tidy.opts = list(blank = FALSE, width.cutoff = 50)

  library(tidyverse)
  library(RefManageR)

  cit.list <- c('base', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs))

  for(i in 1:length(cit.list)) {
      ref <- as.BibEntry(citation(cit.list[i]))
      WriteBib(ref,file="packages.bib",biblatex=TRUE,append=TRUE,verbose=FALSE)
     }
  @
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]